# Why 38000M peak when trying to render image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, vertices, error, memory-management

When I am trying to render an image with 32 samples the peak M gets to 38000 and the crashes with CUDA error for not enough GPU memory.

We just bought a new computer

- Rtx 3070
- 32 ram
- Cpu AMD ryzen 9 5950
- Water cooled

The file takes 10 minutes just to open, thne crashes when trying to go into render view mode

Have 158 million tris
80 million verts and faces

Comment: You might need to reduce the verts in your file first. Blender is not mean to deal with that much of vertices.

Comment: At least with that amount of data you'd need to try to render on CPU first. GPU has less memory. Anyway though there's a lot of geometry and maybe 32GB won't be enough. Try Decimate modifier, also moving different collections to other view layers

Answer (score 1):

It takes up that memory and crashes because 158 M faces is huge. That’s about it.

Try using decimate or some thing to reduce the number of faces, or even use different scenes so it’s broken up in pieces, and then video sequence them together.